# Anchor links within tabs options?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, tabs

I am working with a tabs layout and was wondering if there are any alternatives to anchor links when only using html and css? Are there subanchor links?

I want to link one item in the 1st tab to another item in the 2nd tab. What could I use that would allow me to do this? Anchor links aren't currently working due to the tabs layout.

Thanks!

Code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xsaht

For example, on tab 3, having a word from header 5 link to another word in header 4.

Comment: It's easier to visualize what you're trying to do if you post code here or in JSFiddle.

Comment: I just updated it. :)

Comment: have u tried using `id` and `href`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately when I tried it the accordion sections both go black and the random word used for the id appears. It looks really glitchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative to this,

Instead of using an accordion, anchor links will work within the tabs. I created a table to contain the main headers of the sections at the top with anchor links. It also speeds up the site a little by getting rid of the accordions.

Code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pkvoI